# Nano on Amazon Linux Mangling Text in Config Files

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, apache, nano

I am attempting to edit my httpd.conf file on a ec2 instance of amazon linux using nano while SSHed into it on my Macbook Air running OSX 10.7.4.

i am attempting to change the documentroot to "/home/ec2-user/www" only to discover that what was saved to the file was docume "/home/ec2-user/www" or some other mangled fragment of it.

forgive me i am not sure if this is better suited for stackoverflow, poweruser or server fault.